# what operations are performing in the given coding

Tags: awk

I am having a shell script code like below:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !($0 in a){print "Fail: "$0 " is not found"}' <(cat file3 <(grep -r names file2)) <(grep -r present file1)
```

Can someone explain in the above code what the **awk** is doing here..?

Comment: All those process substitutions i.e. `<(...)` can be refactored if you include sample input with an expected output.

Comment: @anubhava I'm new to shell script. Can you please tell me what is the meaning of this in the code? 1- awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !($0 in a)  , 2 - <(cat file3 <(grep -r names file2)) <(grep -r present file1)

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of question where you can take it apart piece by piece:

- do `grep -r present file1` on it's own and see what it outputs

  - although if "file1" is truly a file and not a directory, then the `-r` option is useless
- `<(...)` is a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) -- it takes the *output* of the script and lets you handle that as a *file*
- Similarly, `<(cat file3 <(grep -r names file2))` concatenates the contents
  of "file3" and the output of the `grep` command.-
- now, the `awk` script

  - `awk 'NR==FNR {do something; next} some more awk code' fileA fileB` is a very common awk idiom

    - `NR == FNR` means "the current record number (out of all files processed so far) is equal to the record number of the current file being processed" -- this can only happen for the first file in the list[1]
    - so, `do something` only for the first file, because `next` won't allow the "some more awk code" to be reached.

Without showing us the contents of the files, there's not much more to say. If you were to show the inputs and output, we can help you understand exactly why you see the results you see.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But can you please explain me what is this part in the code: NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !($0 in a). a is not declared any where but how it is being used here..

Comment: That's how awk works. Click the [tag:awk] tag under your question, then click the "[Learn more...](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info)" link